# Cannot pass request from html/angular to node with express

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to send data from a modal form to node when a button is clicked using express, but I keep getting a blank {} for req.body. I've tried .get, .post, and .all. I've found a lot of similar errors on here but they all deal with body-parser issues which does not appear to be my problem.

Html code:

```
    <html lang="en" ng-app="ValidationApp">
    <div ng-controller="Test1" class="container-fluid" style="position:absolute;">

    <button type="button" class="btn-primary" id="get_input"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#POBI_modal"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i>  Get POBI Data</button><br> 

  <div id="POBI_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:rgba(147, 147, 147, .5);">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title style1" style="font-size:24px;">Please enter your Oracle Log-in Information</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" >

                    <form class="form-group" name="POBI_form" id="POBI_form"  method="get" action="/input">
                        <div class="form-group row">

                            <label style="margin-left:20px;"class="style1"> Version:
                                <select ng-model="working_final" name="working_final" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                                    <option value="working">Working</option>
                                    <option value="final">Final</option>
                                </select>
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="POBI Username" ng-model="username" name="username"
                                       maxlength="6" minlength="6" style="margin-left:5px;" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="POBI Password" ng-model="pwd" name="pwd" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="runfile('input','POBI_form')" style="margin-left:5px;" data-dismiss="modal"
                                ng-disabled="POBI_form.$invalid">Enter information</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Exit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </html>
```

Angular code:

```
<script>
    //when modal is exited wo running, clears all fields

    $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
        $(".modal-body input").val("")
        $(".modal-body select").val("")
    });


    ////////////////////////////////////////
    var app=angular.module('ValidationApp',[]);
        app.controller('Test1', function($scope,$http){

            $scope.testtext='';

            runfile=function(location1,form_name) {
                $scope.$apply(function (){
                    $scope.location1 = location1;

                     var myForm=$scope[form_name]
                    var data={}
                    angular.forEach(myForm,function(value,key){
                        if(value.hasOwnProperty('$modelValue') && typeof value==='object') {
                            data[key]=value.$modelValue
                        }
                    })
                    console.log(data)

                    $scope.Date1=new Date();

                    $http.post('/'+location1,"message=sdfsdfsd",{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}})
                            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                alert('Success')
                            })
                            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                                alert('Error')
                            });


/*                        $http.get('/'+location1)
                            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                if($scope.message1==null){
                                    $scope.message1=headers
                                } else {
                                    $scope.message1=$scope.message1+=data.message1;
                                }

                            })
                            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                                alert('Error')
                            });*/

                });
            };
    });
</script>
```

Node code:

```
var express=require('express');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');

var app=express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var server = app.listen(5439, function() {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
app.post('/input', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
});

app.get('/',function(req,res){
   res.sendFile('html filename');
});
```

Comment: Add the angular code.

Comment: just added, thanks!

Comment: Request information from the console where I get a 404: 
`Request Headers:Host: localhost:5439
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: localhost:5439
Content-Length: 16
Connection: keep-alive Request Body: message=sdfsdfsd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was me trying to GET and POST to the same url - fixed it by using `app.all` and separated the GET and POST code using `if-else` with `req.method`:

```
app.all('*',function(req,res){
    if (req.method=='POST') {
       //POST code here
    } else if (req.method=='GET') {
        //GET code here
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not pass the data in your request. You can do something like:

```
$http.post('/input', data)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('good');
        alert(data)
        // $scope.message1=data.message1;
    }).error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        alert('bad')
        alert(data)
});
```

And on your server side, you could get them like:

```
app.post('/input', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.json();
});
```

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

Comment: I updated the angular, node, and html form code to use post. I now get a success message from the angular code, but still get blank brackets from req.body in node.

Comment: Print the data in the console before passing it in the `$http.post`. Does it have the value?

Comment: yes :  Object { working_final: "working", username: "thtghf", pwd: "fghfghfg" } POST 
XHR 
http://localhost:5439/input

Comment: Print the contents of `req` on the server. What does it show?

Comment: Too long to post here so:  http://txt.do/d6ba7 .The first line is `req.url`, which I am able to access.I am getting a 404 error when trying to POST - very confusing since the GET request is successful.

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest code? You are still sending the `GET` request from Angular.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153882/discussion-between-user3711502-and-prerak-sola).